# State-space representation of gammachirp filter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, signal-processing, control-theory, time-series

Let $h$ be the impulse response of the [gammachirp filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gammatone_filter):

$$ h(t) = \exp(c_1 + c_2 t + c_3 \ln t) \cos(c_4 + c_5 t + c_6 \ln t) $$

The output $y$ of the filter is given by the convolution of the input $x$ and $h$:

$$ y = x \ast h $$

What is the [state-space representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation) of this filter?

Answer (score 2):

The impulse response of a LTI system with a finite dimensional state space can be computed with,

$$
h(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{l l}
C\, e^{A\, t} B + D\, \delta(t) & \text{if } t \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{array} \right.
$$

which should always consist out of a finite sum of exponentials (potentially complex conjugate pairs and/or multiplied by polynomials when $A$ has Jordan blocks of larger than size one).

When $c_3$ and $c_6$ are not zero, then the impulse response you provided can not be written as a finite sum of such terms. Therefore there is no state space model, with a state space of finite size, which behaves exactly like such filter.

Comment: There is no finite linear time invariant state space representation. Thus your justification is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

A state-space representation can either indicate a LTI, LTV or nonlinear system. As @fibonatic said, your system surely does not have a LTI state-space representation. Assume that the system is described in s-s form as:
$$\begin{align}\dot{x}&=f(x,t)+u\\y&=x\end{align}$$
Then we can write
$$\begin{align}\dot{h}&=f(h,t)+\delta(t)\\
&=\left\{\left(c_2+\frac{c_3}t\right)-\left(c_5+\frac{c_6}t\right)\tan(c_4 + c_5 t + c_6 \ln t)\right\}h(t)\\&\stackrel{\Delta}= g(t)h(t)\end{align}$$
This might give us the idea that we can write $f(x,t)$ as
$$f\left(x,t\right)=g(t)x-\delta(t)$$
but as you see, this $f$ will be dependent on the input which contradicts our initial assumption that $f(x,t)$ is independent of $u$. So there can't be any affine state space representation of this filter.

Comment: The system doesn't have a finite-dimensional state-space representation. But infinite-dimensional realizations exist.

Comment: @Pait Correct. Another fact is, the system doesn't have a _real_ state space representation but complex ones can be found.

Comment: You mean a finite-dimension complex representation? Interesting - can you elaborate or point to a source? Thanks!